# How to look up logical partition count and size in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In Cosmos DB, is it possible to see how many logical partitions my database has created and the current fill capacity of each partition? I'd like to know how evenly my partitioning strategy is dividing data. Also, I'd like to prepare for data re-distribution before I hit the 20GB limit on a hot partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure monitor for Cosmos DB. Check out the metrics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't give you size metrics by partition. You can find the partition breakdown by following these steps:

1. Go to the Overview page of your Cosmos DB instance in [Azure Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com)
2. In the Monitoring section select "Metrics (Classic)"
3. Click on the Storage tab
4. Select the database and container of interest
5. In the "Data + Index storage consumed by top partition keys" panel is a chart of data consumption by key.