# cosmos DB - 'Logical Partition" count and number of items per logical partition chart required

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I did follow the answer at [How to look up logical partition count and size in Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095085/how-to-look-up-logical-partition-count-and-size-in-cosmos-db) which led me to "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics#determine-the-throughput-distribution-across-partitions". However, that report no longer appears on Azure portal. All I get is "Top logical partition keys by throughout and storage". I want a list of all my "Logical partitions" mapped to count of items within each logical partition. I want to measure how even the "value" distribution is across each logical partition.

Answer (score -1):

You can find this report here:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's giving me ALL the logical partition keys @stevezhao. It's only giving me the "top" partitions that occupied "significant" storage, >= 4 KB (I am on the 'throughout' tab). I have 100 distinct "Partition Id's". I want to see how many logical partitions these "100 physical Parition Key's" mapped to.